# How can I call a static method from a class variable? It gives an error while importing in another notebook

Tags: python-3.x, class, import, static-methods

I have 2 files: file1 and file2 in the same directory:

Contents of file1:

```
class Class1:
   class_variable = widgets.interactive_output(Class1.static_method, {'index' : index})

   @staticmethod
   def static_method(index):
       //body of the function
```

Contents of file2:

```
from file1 import Class1
```

When i run file2, I get following errors based on calls:

```
When I call it using:
1. Class1.static_method, {'index' : index})
   I get the error:
   NameError: name 'Class1' is not defined

2. static_method, {'index' : index})
   I get the error:
   NameError: name 'static_method' is not defined
```

How can I solve this? Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to `Class1` in the assignment of the class variable, but `Class1` isn't yet defined at that point.

You could skip the class variable in the definition of `Class1` and add it to the class at a later point:

```py
class Class1:
   @staticmethod
   def static_method(index):
       //body of the function

Class1.class_variable = widgets.interactive_output(Class1.static_method, {'index' : index})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you plan to use Class1 in your code, but indeed the issue is that `Class1` is not defined at the point when you reference it. You can use a `classmethod` to define a class attribute.

file1.py

```
class Class1:
    @staticmethod
    def static_method(index):
        //body of the function
        
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls.class_variable = widgets.interactive_output(cls.static_method, {'index' : index})
        return super(Class1, cls).__new__(cls)
```

Here I'm using `__new__` as class method as it runs automatically at the instantiation of the class, but you can define your own.